# MVC или Фреймворк?

Tags: php, mvc

Есть шаблон MVC на с которым я разобрался и могу делать простенькие задачки используя MVC. Но проблема в роутере, он так прописан, что не запускается на линуксе, маке и только в корневой папке опенсервера (переписать роутер не хватает опыта). Мне присылали тестовое задание, я делал, но они запустить не могли и отказывали в работе(обидно, все сделал но толку 0). Что лучше сделать. Найти новый нормальный MVC шаблон и обучиться ему или изучать фреиворк?(но на то уйдет очень очень много времени)

Comment: mvc-шаблон, это в принципе подход к разработке, его суть можно описать одним не длинным предложением. Вы же говорите не о шаблоне, а о его кривой реализации. Фреймворки в отличие от простой реализации шаблона, имеют богатый фунционал и инструментарии для решения множества задач. При этом. написание простых приложений с их использованием остается довольно простой задачей. Поэтому я не знаю, почему вы думаете, что изучение фреймворков займет очень и очень много времени.

Comment: Какой тогда самый не сложный для изучения посоветуете?

Comment: Изучать надо то что требуется под ваши задачи. Хотите устроиться на работу - изучайте то, что там потенциально надо, а не "не сложный". При трудоустройстве вас никто не попросит написать новый фреймворк, вам скажут "мы юзаем вот это, вот те доки, читай". Возьмите что-нибудь из популярного и начните читать документацию и туториалы, [tag:Yii], [tag:Laravel], [tag:Symfony], [tag:CakePHP], [tag:zend], [tag:CodeIgniter] и т.п.

Comment: В первую очередь порекомендовал бы автору обратить внимание на Yii1/2 и Laravel, т.к. они сейчас больше всего спросом пользуются. Порог вхождения у них достаточно низкий (сделал каталог на первом Yii за месяц, второго тогда не было). Если у Вас есть опыт и понимание принципов MVC, то изучение проблем не доставит (у меня знаний не хватало в свое время).